# prisma/codemods doesn't transform findUnique

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I just did an update from version 2.10.1 to version 2.15.0. Furthermore I ran "npx @prisma/codemods update-2.12 ./". Then times only the single findUnique transform. However always the same result comes out:

```
PS C:\App\Backend> npx @prisma/codemods findUnique ./ --print
Executing command: jscodeshift --print --verbose=0 --ignore-config=.gitignore --ignore-pattern=**/node_modules/** -- 
extensions=tsx,ts,js,tsx --parser=tsx --transform 
C:\App\Backend\node_modules\@prisma\codemods\transforms\findUnique.js ./
No files selected, nothing to do.
All done.
Results:
0 errors
0 unmodified
0 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 0.035seconds
```

Why does codemods not recognize the files in my project?

https://github.com/prisma/codemods

Comment: Hey there, thanks for raising this! I work at Prisma and just pinged my colleagues internally to look at the issue you created in the `codemods` repo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be solved here:
https://github.com/prisma/codemods/issues/22
Seems that i have to much subfolders and the script didn't recognized it.